# SQL Database structure - no unique column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a problem with this very simple sql statement:

`SELECT * FROM video NATURAL JOIN user`

I get a warnig ins phpMyAdmin, that there is no unique column in the selection and i cannot edit any values.
But the id column should be unique...

My database structure:

[structure 1](http://s28.postimg.org/xlwz7pi7h/struct1.png)

[structure 2](http://s24.postimg.org/6mhl2fd1x/struct2.png)

- id in video is a primary key.
- id in all other tables are foreign keys pointing to video.id

Could you tell me what is wrong in my structure?

Thanks!
Benjamin

**SOLVED:**

I created a view from my SQL selection. Inside the view I was able to do changes.

Comment: i don't think id in user table is intended to be a video id.  that seems to be a unique id for the user.  you do not have a relationship between these two tables to make the join

Comment: actually for this project the video id needs to be the primary key.
this has several reasons using the video creation api. user.id should refer to video.id

The sql statement works, and I get the results I'm looking for, but I cannot edit them.

Comment: Foreign key in user:
http://s4.postimg.org/fs7xe3twt/struct3.png

Comment: To troubleshoot, replace select * with select video.id.

Comment: But I need more columns.. :)
I do not understand why this is not working..

Comment: @Randy Any two tables can be joined.

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you *declare* the PK & FKs?

Comment: yes i did! I managed to solve the problem.